# Swift Core Data adding extra empty row

Tags: swift, core-data

I have created a view controller to add an row to my Core Data entity, but when i add the entity in the view controller, it also adds an extra empty row to the entity.

But if i use the same code to add a row in the start viewcontroller, this does not happen

```
let moc = DataController().managedObjectContext
let newRow = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Persons", inManagedObjectContext:moc) as! Persons
newRow.name = name.text
newRow.age = NSNumber(int: 34)
do {
    try moc.save()
} catch {
    fatalError( "failure to save context: \(error)")
}
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: never seen someone use the moc from another VC. I don't think this should cause problems. But it is the only thing I see in this fragment of code that is out of place.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean with "adds an extra empty row to the entity"?

Comment: Did you log something?

Comment: It will ad the row/object i want to save, but with that, it also adds an 'empty object' where the strings = "", and the numbers = 0

no :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are creating the object twice.

One way to debug this is to implement `awakeFromInsert` in your `Persons` class, set a breakpoint and check which part of your code is calling it.